# Issue with 'else' sequence using Spotipy/Spotify API

Tags: python, if-statement, spotify, traceback, spotipy

My team and I (newbies to python) have written the following code to generate spotify songs related to a specific city and related terms.
If the user inputs a city that is not in our CITY_KEY_WORDS list, then it tells the user that the input will be added to a requests file, and then writes the input to a file.
The code is as follows:

```
from random import shuffle
from typing import Any, Dict, List
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
sp = spotipy.Spotify(
    auth_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id="",
                                          client_secret="")
)
CITY_KEY_WORDS = {
    'london': ['big ben', 'fuse'],
    'paris': ['eiffel tower', 'notre dame', 'louvre'],
    'manhattan': ['new york', 'new york city', 'nyc', 'empire state', 'wall street', ],
    'rome': ['colosseum', 'roma', 'spanish steps', 'pantheon', 'sistine chapel', 'vatican'],
    'berlin': ['berghain', 'berlin wall'],
}

def main(city: str, num_songs: int) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
    if city in CITY_KEY_WORDS:
        """Searches Spotify for songs that are about `city`. Returns at most `num_songs` tracks."""
        results = []
        # Search for songs that have `city` in the title
        results += sp.search(city, limit=50)['tracks']['items']  # 50 is the maximum Spotify's API allows
        # Search for songs that have key words associated with `city`
        if city.lower() in CITY_KEY_WORDS.keys():
            for related_term in CITY_KEY_WORDS[city.lower()]:
                results += sp.search(related_term, limit=50)['tracks']['items']
        # Shuffle the results so that they are not ordered by key word and return at most `num_songs`
        shuffle(results)
        return results[: num_songs]
    else:
        print("Unfortunately, this city is not yet in our system. We will add it to our requests file.")
        with open('requests.txt', 'r') as text_file:
            request = text_file.read()
        request = request + city + '\n'
        with open('requests.txt', 'w+') as text_file:
            text_file.write(request)

def display_tracks(tracks: List[Dict[str, Any]]) -> None:
    """Prints the name, artist and URL of each track in `tracks`"""
    for num, track in enumerate(tracks):
        # Print the relevant details
        print(f"{num + 1}. {track['name']} - {track['artists'][0]['name']} {track['external_urls']['spotify']}")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    city = input("Virtual holiday city? ")
    number_of_songs = input("How many songs would you like? ")
    tracks = main(city, int(number_of_songs))
    display_tracks(tracks)
```

The code runs fine for the "if" statement (if someone enters a city we have listed). **But when the else statement is run, 2 errors come up after the actions have been executed ok** (it prints and writes the user's input into a file).

The errors that come up are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 48, in <module>
    display_tracks(tracks)
  File "...", line 41, in display_tracks
    for num, track in enumerate(tracks):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Please excuse my lack of knowledge, but please could someone help with this issue?

We would also like to create a playlist of the songs at the end, however have been facing difficulties with this.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Step through your code and see what causes the error -- `tracks` is `None`. You can't iterate over a `None`. Why is `tracks` set to `None`? That's an exercise for you to find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main` function does not have a `return` statement in the `else` clause and that causes `tracks` to be `None`. Iterating on `tracks` when it's `None` is what's causing the error.
There are a few things you can do to improve the code:

- separation of concerns: the `main` function is doing two different things, checking the input and fetching the tracks.
- do `.lower()` once in the beginning so you don't have to repeat it.
- following documentation conventions.
- checking the response before using it
- some code cleaning

see below the changes I suggested above:

```
def fetch_tracks(city: str, num_songs: int) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
    """Searches Spotify for songs that are about `city`.

    :param city: TODO: TBD
    :param num_songs:  TODO: TBD
    :return: at most `num_songs` tracks.
    """
    results = []
    for search_term in [city, *CITY_KEY_WORDS[city]]:
        response = sp.search(search_term, limit=50)
        if response and 'tracks' in response and 'items' in response['tracks']:
            results += response['tracks']['items']
    # Shuffle the results so that they are not ordered by key word and return
    # at most `num_songs`
    shuffle(results)
    return results[: num_songs]


def display_tracks(tracks: List[Dict[str, Any]]) -> None:
    """Prints the name, artist and URL of each track in `tracks`"""
    for num, track in enumerate(tracks):
        # Print the relevant details
        print(
            f"{num + 1}. {track['name']} - {track['artists'][0]['name']} "
            f"{track['external_urls']['spotify']}")


def main():
    city = input("Virtual holiday city? ")
    city = city.lower()
    # Check the input city and handle unsupported cities.
    if city not in CITY_KEY_WORDS:
        print("Unfortunately, this city is not yet in our system. "
              "We will add it to our requests file.")
        with open('requests.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(f"{city}\n")
        exit()

    number_of_songs = input("How many songs would you like? ")
    tracks = fetch_tracks(city, int(number_of_songs))
    display_tracks(tracks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a helpful and comprehensive answer, as a newbie to python this was so insightful! Thank you for your kindness, I hope you have a wonderful rest of the year :)

Answer (score 0):

When your `if`-statement is executed, you return a list of items and feed them into the `display_tracks()` function. But what happens when the `else`-statement is executed? You add the request to your text-file, but do not return anything (or a `NoneType` item) and feed that into `display_tracks()`. `display_tracks` then iterates of this `NoneType`-item, throwing your exception.

You only want to show the tracks if there actually are any tracks to display. One way to do this would be to move the call of `display_tracks()` into your `main` function, but then the same error would be thrown if no tracks are found to your search-terms. Another solution would be to first check if your `tracks` are not empty or to catch the `TypeError`-exception with something like

```
tracks = main(city, int(number_of_songs))
try:
    display_tracks(tracks)
except TypeError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is greatly appreciated!